# Laravel 5 Configuring LOCAL vs CDN resources for DEV vs PRODUCTION (e.g. bootstrap, jquery, angular)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, resources

Sorry in advance if this was answered elsewhere. My search words returned nothing

I would like to have two different configurations for retrieving resource files like jQuery, Bootstrap, Angular... etc

In Production, I would like to retrieve from CDNs, e.g. for Bootstrap:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

In Development, I can be offline or with unreliable internet connectivity, so I would like to configure it to access some locally downloaded version, e.g.:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('assets/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
```

How do I configure in such a way that I can switch between the two setups?

Comment: You shall store two main path i.e., `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/` and `https://yourlocalpath` and point it accordingly

Answer (score 2):

If you dont satisfy with explicitly if ... else ... structure but prefer configures then this packages would be best suited: [Stolz/Assets](https://github.com/Stolz/Assets#collections)

Regards,

Comment: Thanks. This is good to know though it will still require some condition to distinguish between local and CDN resources

Comment: Yes but instead of repeat your if ... else ... structure for every page, you can group them up in the config and detect environment is production or development at runtime to insert appropriate assets.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to avoid evaluation every time the page is loaded, you can [extend blade](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#extending-blade), e.g.:

```
\Blade::directive('cdnasset', function ($expression) {
    if (\App::environment('local')) {
        return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php URL::asset'.$expression.'; ?>">';
    } else {
        $css = substr($expression, 2, -2);
        return  '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com'.$css.'">';
    }
});
```

This will cache the evaluation in `storage/framework/views/`, so remember to clear your views with artisan if you test it!

Answer (score 1):

```
@if(App::environment('local'))
    {{-- The environment is local --}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('assets/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
@else
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
@endif
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this is evaluated every time the template or page is accessed, right?
Is there are deployment-specific config?